# Java String strip with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, trim

How can I remove leading & trailing chars in a certain range (preferably with a regex)?

for instance if I want to remove leading & trailing english letters:

```
aa11bb22cc ----> 11bb22
```

I noticed that the recommended apache commons `StringUtils.strip()` utility method doesn't support regex input. For example:

```
String a = "aa11bb22cc";
a = StringUtils.strip(a, "[a-zA-Z]");
System.out.println(a);
```

Outputs:

```
11bb22cc
```

ie `[a-zA-Z]` was handled as a list of 7 literal characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use java's [`String#replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to replace with blank (ie "delete") the target chars:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)^[a-z]+|[a-z]+$", "");
```

The regex means "ignoring case, match letters immediately after start *or* immediately before end"

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern

```
^[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/62)

```
^               # Start of string/line
[a-zA-Z]            # Character Class [a-zA-Z]
+               # (one or more)(greedy)
|               # OR
[a-zA-Z]            # Character Class [a-zA-Z]
+               # (one or more)(greedy)
$               # End of string/line
```